# region Monitoring on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager

I was just wondering what devices support region monitoring? I know iPhone 4 does, but does iPad 2 support this?

Also the documentation suggests:

```
For this reason, Core Location limits the number of regions that may be simultaneously monitored by a single application.
```

What is the region limit that can be monitored using this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that non-3G devices don't currently support region monitoring: my testing indicates that it's exclusively based on cell-tower handoffs, so the other location services (Wi-Fi and GPS) can't provide that functionality. It's probably best not to base your code on assumptions about specific hardware: CLLocationManager has a `maximumRegionMonitoringDistance` property which will return `-1` on devices that don't support region monitoring.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I just wanted to know this info to make a decision whether to use region monitoring on my apps or use the classic significantChangeLocation. I asked in the apple developer forum and one of a rep said that this is available on iPad 2 3G

Comment: This must have changed in the iOS 8 SDK because this never returns -1 for me, check my answer if you have the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The iPad2 uses the same location framework as the iPhone and iPad 1.  It should work.

I'm not sure what the limit is.

Comment: The software API is the frame, but the hardware capabilities are different which is what limits functionality on non-3G devices.

Comment: Same for the Touch.  What is in question is if the iPad 2 supports region monitoring at all, which it does within the limits of the API and the capabilities of the device.  But again there is nothing about the iPad 2 that changes how Core Location works.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed an iPad2(without sim) and iPod not add regions successfully. Use this code to guard your monitoring code from being ran for devices which do not support region monitoring in iOS8 SDK:

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.integerValue >= 7 &&
    ![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:CLRegion.class]) {
    return;
}else if(![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable])
    return;
```